# How can I modify the PolylinesOptions of Angular Components map-Directions-renderer?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-material2, angular-components

hi I'm trying to edit the PolylinesOptions of the `<map-directions-renderer>`  component 
 ([component developed by Angular team](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/map-directions-renderer/README.md)) and I can't get results

I need to generate multiple renderers to generate different paths independent of each other,
with these PolylinesOptios is to generate a custom line to identify the routes from each other. [( Live Example )](http://jsfiddle.net/p5gmyd0z/5/)

> [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuTEv.png)

> [Obtained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpIQh.png)

that's why all renderers are bound to the same variable

```
@ViewChildren('directionsRender') directionsRenders : QueryList<ElementRef<google.maps.DirectionsRenderer> >;
```

```
  this.directionsRenderOption = {
    draggable:false,
    suppressInfoWindows:true,
    markerOptions:{
      draggable: false,
      clickable:false,
    };,
    polylineOptions:{
      strokeColor: '#9966ff',
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      icons: [{
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          fillOpacity: 1,
          scale: 3
        },
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '1px'
      }],
    }
  }
```

```
    <google-map
        #map 
        height="100%" 
        width="null" 
        [options]="this.mapOptions"
        (tilesloaded)="tilesLoaded()"
        *ngIf="this.itemList.length != 0"
    >
        <map-directions-renderer 
            #directionsRender 
            *ngFor="let directionResult of directionsResults"
            [options]="directionsRenderOption" 
            [directions]="directionResult" 
        >
        </map-directions-renderer>
    </google-map>
```

I already tried to insert the options through a QueryList from a @ViewChildren and all the nativeElements return undefined in their methods but if they return the ElementRef from the Dom

it only happens with the PolylineOption, since if I modify for example the options of the markers if it applies these properties, Example: Modify the MarkerOptions of the rendering options to draggable, if you apply the changes.

> [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5jC4.png)